# Altitude of a Triangle: Showing indeed perpendicular

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> $\textbf{Question:}$ Why can we drop a perpendicular $h$ between the two points along the base of the triangle below where $\alpha, \beta\leq 90^\circ$?

[image]

The reason I'm wondering this is because often times when dealing with isosceles triangles, I see $h$ is often constructed by connecting $M$ to the top vertex by defining $M$ to be the midpoint which implies the angle along the base is indeed ninety degrees by using the perpendicular bisector theorem. So, do I need to define where $M$ is first for this example to show construction of $h$ will be indeed $90^\circ$ or no? That's where I am getting confused..

Here is a picture.

[image]

Comment: So the question is 'why can we draw an altitude' or 'how do you draw an altitude precisely'? I don't really understand it...

Comment: Why can we draw an altitude. Why is it feasible? Is it due to betweenness? I'm not concerned about how to draw it with a compass and a straight edge.

Comment: I DON'T want the compass.

Comment: What do you think geometry is about? Why do you reject the compass and straightedge?

Comment: I'm not concerned about the construction of it by an example. I want the proof.

Comment: What exactly do you want proved? That there is a point $M$ on the line through the two lower vertices such that the angle between the $h$ segment and that line is a right angle? Or that if such a point exists, it will be between the two vertices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let we say about $\Delta ABC$ and let $M$ placed on the line $AB$ such that $A$ placed between $M$ and $B$.

Thus, $\measuredangle CAM<90^{\circ},$ which gives $\alpha>90^{\circ},$ which is a contradiction.

By the same way we can get a contradiction if $B$ placed between $M$ and $A$.

Id est, $M$ placed on the side $AB$.

Comment: Rather, we always have $\measuredangle CAM<90^{\circ}$, but if $A$ were between $M$ and $B$, $\angle CAB$ would be the supplement of $\angle CAM$ rather than the same angle.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov If $M\in AB$ it's not always so!  For example: $M\equiv A$. We have no an angle!

Comment: So, I made a picture above. Why do we know $\measuredangle CAM<90^\circ$?

Comment: @W. G Because $\Delta CAM$ is a right-angled triangle.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh!!!! I get it thank you!

Comment: @W. G. You are welcome! It's indeed, not so trivial problem.